# How to create a multidimensional picture from a moving camera

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, feature-extraction

I am looking for a smart way to solve the following problem:

I have a camera, which is mounted to a car. The car is driving on a road.
What I want is a top-view image of the road surface, with all images aligned, but not stitched together.

The camera can maybe sees the next 20 meters, but a new photo is taken every 2 meters (depending on velocity).

My take on the problem is to calculate the top view with a perspective-transformation and after this to do a feature based matching.
However the feature based matching is pretty slow (and a road is not the best place to search for features).
I was wondering if there are faster methods around that I don't know about?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at some SLAM algorithms, a good candidate is [ORB-SLAM2](https://github.com/raulmur/ORB_SLAM2). However, if you only use one normal camera, the result may be not as good compared to, say, a depth camera or pair of cameras (stereo camera).